# strike tag inside an angular literal

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to insert a string in a button via angular literal, but on a condition. And also strike out the string if the condition is met.

```
button {{(players > 2) ? 'Start' : '<strike>Cannot start</strike>'}}
```

such that it would appear like either as <kbd>Start</kbd> or <kbd><strike>Cannot start</strike></kbd>

but it doesn't work like that for some reason. It shows <kbd>{{(players > 2) ? 'Start' : '<strike>Cannot start</strike>'}}</kbd>

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Older versions did not support the ternary operator.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos ternary operator works fine, its the `<strike>` tag inside that's the problem i think

Answer (score 0):

> if you are using angular 2/4 then you can use it.

```
<button *ngIf="players > 2">Start</button>
<button *ngIf="players < 2"><s>Cannot start</s></button>
```